# Structures for beginners

Tags: c, struct, structure

I am new to structures and I'm trying to do some tutorials to see if i understood well what i've been learning. Here's the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct variables{
    float Vx;
    float Vy;
    float Vz;
}velocity;

int main(){
    velocity *pv;
    pv = (velocity*)malloc(sizeof(velocity));

    pv[0].Vx = 1;
    pv[0].Vy = 2;
    pv[0].Vz = 3;

free(pv);

return 0;
}
```

So my questions are 2:

- Did I allocate the three variables in correct way?
- Since I'm using the array notation why should I ever write `[0]`
  instead of `[1]` or `[2]` or so on?

Comment: The array subscripting notation is misleading here.  I recommend you use `pv->Vx = 1` etc instead.  Also don't cast the return value of `malloc` and unless you feel a strong urge to do so, refrain from `typedef`'ing your `struct`s.  Oh, and check whether `malloc` succeeded or returned `NULL`.

Comment: @5gon12eder What is your rationale against typedefing structs?

Comment: @2501 It adds additional complexity / confusion at no real benefit.  In the above example, why have the two names `variables` and `velocity` when `struct velocity` would just do?  I also don't like obscuring the semantics of a program by hiding the `struct` in a `typedef`.

Comment: @5gon12eder How is it adding to the confusion or complexity. You have either have a struct type or a type. Just use one. *In the above example, why have the two names variables and velocity when struct velocity would just do?* I don't understand this part. `velocity` without the struct prefix is completely identical to `struct velocity`, except you don't have to type `struct`. Less text to type is reducing "complexity".

Comment: @2501 You have hit upon one of the major stylistic debates of C.  Every programmer will feel **very** strongly about whether you should typedef a struct.  They just won't all agree.

Comment: You might consider looking into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, but the syntax you are using is a bit odd. The operator `[n]` means: Take the pointer's address (in your case the value in `pv`), increment it by n, and dereference it. Since you are not incrementing the address (n = 0), you can just dereference it. You do this with `*pv`, or simply with `pv->`. You only need the `[]` operator when you have allocated **more than one** struct, and want to set the address to one of these structs. `pv[3]` would then be the same as `*(pv+3)`. But you first have to allocate more space if you want to use a pointer as an array:

`malloc(sizeof(velocity) * 4)`

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I found a little mistake: It should be `malloc(... * 4)` when we want `pv[3]` to be valid (because like any array, it goes from 0 to 3, which sums up to 4 elements).

Answer (score 5):

To answer the first question: yes, your code is completely correct. (You even `free`'d it properly, I'm a bit proud!)

As for the second question, I'm a bit unsure what you mean, but when you call `malloc(N * sizeof(type))` where *N* is some integer (in your case, it would just be `1`), you are in essence just creating an array of *N* elements of `type`. So `pv[0]` is the first and only element in this array when *N*=1, and `pv[1]`, `pv[2]` etc don't exist.

You should, however, use the syntax `pv->Vx` instead of `pv[0].Vx`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer! I actually thought that sizeof(velocity) would allocate enough space for 3 floats (3*sizeof(float))... I also tried to substitute 0 with 1 and it still works... how is that possible?

Comment: `sizeof(velocity)` will allocate enough space for 1 `velocity` variable.  This will be enough to hold the 3 floats that make up a `velocity`.  As for `pv[1]` working, it means yuou got lucky and were allowed to access that memory.

Comment: `pv[1]` is accessing memory right after the end of the array. This leads to so-called *undefined behavior*, which means that what happens is completely up to the compiler and/or operating system what to do. In your case, you got lucky, but your program could just as well have crashed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you used your variables in proper way.
2. in your code, you've only allocated memory for one instance of the variable. so, it's same if you write `pv[0].Vx` or `pv->Vx`. If you want to allocate memory for `n` number of instances, you can use `pv[k].Vx`, where `0<=k<=n-1`.

SideNote: Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.